# Visual Studio filter text search results by class attribute

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, search, attributes

For example there is a class with an attribute :

```
[Author("Foo Bar")]
class SampleClass
{
     // Class
}
```

In Visual Studio 10, is it possible to search text throughout the solution and to filter by author attribute? Maybe i am missing something.

Comment: Go to you AuthorAttribute class, right click and pick show all references?

Comment: @TonyHopkinson it's not that useful. there are usually a lot classes by an author, manually searching each one is too much hassle. what i want is to type a query which is only searched inside the target author classes.

Comment: Ohhh! I'd probably write something to do that sort of thing, using a tool like Grep

Comment: @TonyHopkinson If no one answers the question i will be forced to write a solution myself. Most likely using a lightweight c# parser. But, it kind of sucks to jump from an IDE to a command line app just to do a basic search.

Comment: Yeah it's a  bit of a one off, I dare say most with a similar need, went brute force, or gave it up. You could do an add on though to get round switching in and out of VS

Comment: This feature would become especially useful if classes are split up into many files (partial). I would have expected an indexed search feature inside Visual Studio. Contrary to a reasonable user experience the Class View seems to be completely unaware of attributes.